# How to Display Error icon in all the cell in devExpress Grid in windows form in vb.net..?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

[image]

I want to draw error icon in all the cell which are validated at a time in datageid in devExpres.

I was draw a error icon in cell but there is some problem,
 1.Color of the cell is overwritted on the error icon.
 2.Text of grid and error icon both are mixed that why text is not display excat.

I want perfect example. Is any one have solution?

Comment: iam not sure what you want to achieve but take a look at ValidateRow event.

Comment: I already done that task, but its validated only row by Row, But i want to if error icon display in perticular cell in perticular row, but when ever focused goes in another row error icon was remove from those cells.

Comment: Try the ValidatingEditor event ;)

Comment: In validatingEditor it is not possible to persists the error icon in all the cell, but i can check the validation but not solving my issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `CustomDrawEventHandler` as shown below

```
Private Sub CustomDrawEventHandler(. ByVal .. As )

        If IsError(...) Then

            e.EditViewInfo.ErrorIconText = "IsNull"

            e.EditViewInfo.ShowErrorIcon = True

            e.EditViewInfo.FillBackground = True

            e.EditViewInfo.ErrorIcon = DXErrorProvider.GetErrorIconInternal(ErrorType.Critical)

            e.EditViewInfo.CalcViewInfo(e.Graphics)

        End If

End Sub
```

For more info check this DevExpress Kb article:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1933